Pygame inherited classes acting differently
I'm making a python project for school, and created a general Enemy Class, which is then to be inherited by every common enemy. I created a Goblin Class that inherits this, and it works as expected, so I created another one for an Orc Class that also inherits the enemy class, and yet the image for the orc is being blitted to the wrong position. The init for both function are exactly the same, even using the same spritesheet as I was trying to debug the issue, so the only difference is the Class name, and yet it still has this issue.
enemy.py:
import pygame
from settings import *
import random

red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
transparent = (0, 0, 0, 0)

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height, health, rect_width, start_pos, group, animation_incrementer = 36, attack_range = 54, attack_damage = 10):
        super().__init__(group)
        
        self.velocity_x = 0
        self.velocity_y = 0

        self.player_in_alert_range = False
        self.trigger_range = 160 * 0 * (screen_width / 640)
        self.attack_range = attack_range * (screen_width / 640)

        self.state = "idle"
        self.timeout = 0.3
        self.attack_cooldown = 0.2
        self.speed = base_speed

        self.los_blocked = False
        self.target_seen = False
        self.target_last_location = None

        self.color = green

        self.action = "idle"
        self.facing = "right"

        self.width = width * (screen_width / 640)
        self.height = height * (screen_width / 640)
        self.rect_width = rect_width * (screen_width / 640)

        self.max_health = health
        self.health = self.max_health

        self.can_move = True
        self.can_attack = True
        self.attack_started = False
        self.attack_finished = False
        self.attack_damage = attack_damage
        self.dealt_damage = False
        self.target_dead = False

        self.hurt = False
        self.hurt_started = False
        self.hurt_finished = False
        self.damaged = False

        self.dead = False
        self.end_of_death = False

        # Knockback variables
        self.knockback_active = False
        self.knockback_direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.knockback_speed = 1000  # Adjust for desired knockback speed
        self.knockback_duration = 0.1  # Knockback effect duration in seconds
        self.knockback_timer = 0  # Tracks the time remaining for knockback
    
        # Frame & Animation variables
        self.frame_counter = 0
        self.current_frame = 0
        self.animation_incrementer = animation_incrementer

        self.home_pos = (start_pos[0] * (screen_width / 640), start_pos[1] * (screen_width / 640))
        self.wander_pos = None
        self.wander_range = 128
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(start_pos[0] * (screen_width / 640), start_pos[1] * (screen_width / 640))

    def add_to_camera_group(self, group):
        super().__init__(group)

    def extract_frames(self, frame_width, frame_height, current_sprite_sheet, frames_array):
        frame_width = frame_width
        frame_height = frame_height

        for y in range(0, current_sprite_sheet.get_height(), frame_height):
            for x in range(0, current_sprite_sheet.get_width(), frame_width):
                frame = current_sprite_sheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(x, y, frame_width, frame_height))
                frame = pygame.transform.scale(frame, (self.width, self.height))
                frames_array.append(frame)


    def draw(self, screen, offset, target):
        adjusted_rect = self.rect.move(-offset.x, -offset.y)
        adjusted_img_rect = self.image_rect.move(-offset.x, -offset.y)
        adjusted_circ = [int(self.pos[0] - offset.x) + (self.rect_width / 2), int(self.pos[1] - offset.y) + (self.height / 2)]
        
        # Calculate the center of the circle
        centercirc = (adjusted_circ[0], adjusted_circ[1])

        # Create a new Surface with per-pixel alpha
        circle_surface = pygame.Surface((self.trigger_range * 2, self.trigger_range * 2), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        circle_surface = circle_surface.convert_alpha()

        adjusted_player_rect = target.move(-offset.x, -offset.y)

        # Draw the semi-transparent circle on the new Surface
        # pygame.draw.circle(circle_surface, (0, 0, 255, 100), (self.trigger_range, self.trigger_range), self.trigger_range)

        # Blit the new Surface with the semi-transparent circle onto the screen
        # screen.blit(circle_surface, (adjusted_circ[0] - self.trigger_range, adjusted_circ[1] - self.trigger_range))

        self.line_to_player = (adjusted_rect.center, adjusted_player_rect.center)

        # pygame.draw.line(screen, self.color, *self.line_to_player, width=4)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, blue, adjusted_img_rect, 2, 1)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, adjusted_rect, 2, 1)


        if self.player_in_alert_range:
            self.color = red
        elif self.state == "searching":
            self.color = blue
        else:
            self.color = green

    def check_collision_with_player(self, target):
        distance = pygame.math.Vector2(target.center).distance_to(self.rect.center)

        if self.health > 0:
            if distance <= self.trigger_range:
                self.player_in_alert_range = True
                self.target_seen = True
            else:
                self.player_in_alert_range = False
            
            if self.target_seen: 
                if distance <= self.attack_range:
                    self.state = "attacking"
                    self.action = "idle"
                    self.can_move = False
                else:
                    self.state = "aggressive"
                    self.can_move = True

                if self.los_blocked:
                    self.state = "searching"
            else:
                self.state = "idle"

            if self.hurt:
                self.state = "hurt"
                self.hurt_started = True

                if not self.damaged:
                    self.take_damage(target)

            if target.left < self.rect.left:
                self.facing = "left"
            else:
                self.facing = "right"

    def update_self(self, target, offset, dt):
        self.velocity_x = 0
        self.velocity_y = 0

        if self.attack_cooldown > 0:
            self.attack_cooldown -= dt

        # If knockback is active, handle knockback movement
        if self.knockback_active:
            self.velocity_x = self.knockback_direction.x * self.knockback_speed * dt
            self.velocity_y = self.knockback_direction.y * self.knockback_speed * dt

            # Update the knockback timer
            self.knockback_timer -= dt
            if self.knockback_timer <= 0:
                self.knockback_active = False  # End knockback after duration

            self.action = "hurt"
        else:
            target_pos = pygame.math.Vector2(target.center) - offset
            goblin_pos = pygame.math.Vector2(self.rect.center) - offset

            if self.state == "hurt":
                self.action = "hurt"

            elif self.state == "aggressive":
                self.chase_target(dt, target, offset)

            elif self.state == "searching" and self.target_last_location:
                    target_pos = pygame.math.Vector2(self.target_last_location) - offset

                    direction = target_pos - goblin_pos

                    distance = direction.length()
                    
                    if distance != 0:  # Avoid division by zero
                        direction = direction.normalize()
                        
                        # Update the goblin's velocity
                        self.velocity_x = direction.x * self.speed * dt
                        self.velocity_y = direction.y * self.speed * dt

            elif self.state == "attacking":
                self.handle_attacking(dt)
            
            elif self.state == "idle":
                # self.handle_wandering(dt, offset)
                self.action = "idle"

            if self.hurt_started and not self.hurt:
                self.handle_hurt()

            if self.health <= 0:
                self.handle_death()

            if self.attack_finished:
                self.attack_finished = False
                self.attack_started = False
                self.action = "idle"
                self.dealt_damage = False


    def chase_target(self, dt, target, offset):
        target_pos = pygame.math.Vector2(target.center) - offset
        goblin_pos = pygame.math.Vector2(self.rect.center) - offset

        if self.timeout > 0:
            self.timeout -= dt

        if self.timeout <= 0 and self.can_move:
            self.action = "running"
            direction = target_pos - goblin_pos

            distance = direction.length()
            
            if distance != 0:  # Avoid division by zero
                direction = direction.normalize()
                
                # Update the goblin's velocity
                self.velocity_x = direction.x * self.speed * dt
                self.velocity_y = direction.y * self.speed * dt
        
        if self.target_last_location:
            self.target_last_location = None

    def handle_attacking(self, dt):
        if self.attack_cooldown <= 0:
            self.action = "attacking"

            if self.attack_started == False:
                self.frame_counter = 0
                self.attack_started = True

    def handle_hurt(self):
        if self.hurt_finished:
            self.hurt_finished = False
            self.hurt_started = False
        else:
            self.hurt_finished = True

        self.damaged = False
    
    def take_damage(self, target):
        self.health -= 10
        self.damaged = True

        # Activate knockback
        self.knockback_active = True
        self.knockback_timer = self.knockback_duration

        # Calculate knockback direction (away from the player)
        direction_to_player = pygame.math.Vector2(self.rect.center) - pygame.math.Vector2(target.center)
        if direction_to_player.length() != 0:
            self.knockback_direction = direction_to_player.normalize()
    
    def handle_death(self):
        if self.hurt_finished:
            self.state = "dead"
            self.action = "dead"
            if not self.dead:
                self.frame_counter = 0
                self.current_frame = 0
                self.dead = True

        self.can_move = False
        self.can_attack = False

    def handle_wandering(self, dt, offset):
        if not self.wander_pos:
            rand_x = random.randint(-self.wander_range, self.wander_range) * (screen_width / 640)
            rand_y= random.randint(-self.wander_range, self.wander_range) * (screen_width / 640)
            self.wander_pos = (self.home_pos[0] + rand_x, self.home_pos[1] + rand_y)

        elif self.wander_pos and self.pos != self.wander_pos:
            target_pos = pygame.math.Vector2(self.wander_pos)
            goblin_pos = pygame.math.Vector2(self.rect.center)

            self.action = "running"
            direction = target_pos - goblin_pos

            distance = direction.length()
            
            if distance != 0:  # Avoid division by zero
                direction = direction.normalize()
                
                # Update the goblin's velocity
                self.velocity_x = direction.x * self.speed * dt
                self.velocity_y = direction.y * self.speed * dt

        if tuple(map(int, self.wander_pos)) == self.rect.center:
            self.wander_pos = None

    def update_target_pos(self, dt, target, offset):
        self.check_collision_with_player(target)
        self.update_self(target, offset, dt)

    def update_frame(self, dt):
        self.frame_counter += self.animation_incrementer * dt

        if self.action == "idle":
            self.current_frame = (int(self.frame_counter)) % len(self.idle_frames)
            self.image = self.idle_frames[self.current_frame]

        elif self.action == "running":
            self.current_frame = (int(self.frame_counter)) % len(self.running_frames)
            self.image = self.running_frames[self.current_frame]

        elif self.action == "attacking":
            self.current_frame = (int(self.frame_counter) % (len(self.attack1_frames)))
            self.image = self.attack1_frames[self.current_frame]

            if self.current_frame == len(self.attack1_frames) - 1:
                self.attack_finished = True
                self.attack_cooldown = 0.2
        
        elif self.action == "hurt":
            self.current_frame = (int(self.frame_counter) % (len(self.hurt_frames)))
            self.image = self.hurt_frames[self.current_frame]

            if self.current_frame == len(self.hurt_frames) - 1 and self.hurt == False:
                self.hurt_finished = True
        
        elif self.action == "dead":
            self.current_frame = (int(self.frame_counter) % (len(self.death_frames) + 1))
            
            if self.end_of_death == True:

                self.image = self.death_frames[len(self.death_frames) - 1]
            else:
                if self.current_frame == len(self.death_frames):
                    self.end_of_death = True
                else:
                    self.image = self.death_frames[self.current_frame]

        # Scale the image according to the current width and height
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (self.width, self.height))

        # Update the rect size and position based on the new image size
        self.rect.size = (self.rect_width, self.height)
        self.image_rect = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)

        if self.facing == "right":
            self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False)
        if self.facing == "left":
            self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, False, False)

    def move(self, dt):
        self.pos += pygame.math.Vector2(self.velocity_x, self.velocity_y)

        self.rect.topleft = self.pos
        self.image_rect.center = self.rect.center

    def update_incrementer(self):
        pass

    def update(self, dt):
        if self.target_dead:
            self.state = "idle"
            self.action = "idle"

        self.update_incrementer()
        self.update_frame(dt)
        self.move(dt)


Goblin.py:
import pygame
from settings import * 

from enemy.base import Enemy

class Goblin(Enemy):
    def __init__(self, group, start_pos=(650, 1000)):
        rect_width = 30
        height = 45

        super().__init__(width=116, height=height, health=20, rect_width=rect_width, group=group, start_pos=start_pos, animation_incrementer=24, attack_range=0, attack_damage = 15)
        
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2((start_pos[0] - (rect_width / 2)) * (screen_width / 640), (start_pos[1] - (height / 2)) * (screen_width / 640))

        self.idle_sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load('assets/enemy/goblin/idle.png').convert_alpha()
        self.running_sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load('assets/enemy/goblin/run.png').convert_alpha()
        self.attack1_sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load('assets/enemy/goblin/attack1.png').convert_alpha()
        self.hurt_sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load('assets/enemy/goblin/hurt.png').convert_alpha() 
        self.death_sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load('assets/enemy/goblin/death.png').convert_alpha()

        self.idle_frames = []
        self.running_frames = []
        self.attack1_frames = []
        self.hurt_frames = []
        self.death_frames = []

        self.extract_frames(116, 45, self.idle_sprite_sheet, self.idle_frames)
        self.extract_frames(116, 44, self.running_sprite_sheet, self.running_frames)
        self.extract_frames(116, 53, self.attack1_sprite_sheet, self.attack1_frames)
        self.extract_frames(116, 63, self.hurt_sprite_sheet, self.hurt_frames)
        self.extract_frames(116, 41, self.death_sprite_sheet, self.death_frames)

        self.image = self.idle_frames[self.current_frame]
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (self.width, self.height))

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.pos[0], self.pos[1], 30 * (screen_width / 640), 45 * (screen_width / 640))
        self.image_rect = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)

Orc.py:
import pygame
from settings import * 

from enemy.base import Enemy

class MaskedOrc(Enemy):
    def __init__(self, group, start_pos=(650, 1000)):
        rect_width = 30
        height = 45

        super().__init__(width=116, height=height, health=20, rect_width=rect_width, group=group, start_pos=start_pos, animation_incrementer=24, attack_range=0, attack_damage = 15)
        
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2((start_pos[0] - (rect_width / 2)) * (screen_width / 640), (start_pos[1] - (height / 2)) * (screen_width / 640))

        self.idle_sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load('assets/enemy/goblin/idle.png').convert_alpha()
        self.running_sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load('assets/enemy/goblin/run.png').convert_alpha()
        self.attack1_sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load('assets/enemy/goblin/attack1.png').convert_alpha()
        self.hurt_sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load('assets/enemy/goblin/hurt.png').convert_alpha() 
        self.death_sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load('assets/enemy/goblin/death.png').convert_alpha()

        self.idle_frames = []
        self.running_frames = []
        self.attack1_frames = []
        self.hurt_frames = []
        self.death_frames = []

        self.extract_frames(116, 45, self.idle_sprite_sheet, self.idle_frames)
        self.extract_frames(116, 44, self.running_sprite_sheet, self.running_frames)
        self.extract_frames(116, 53, self.attack1_sprite_sheet, self.attack1_frames)
        self.extract_frames(116, 63, self.hurt_sprite_sheet, self.hurt_frames)
        self.extract_frames(116, 41, self.death_sprite_sheet, self.death_frames)

        self.image = self.idle_frames[self.current_frame]
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (self.width, self.height))

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.pos[0], self.pos[1], 30 * (screen_width / 640), 45 * (screen_width / 640))
        self.image_rect = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)

Function that creates the enemies from tmx data:
        elif obj.type in ('Enemy'):
            match obj.enemy:
                case 'goblin':
                    enemy = Goblin(camera_group, start_pos=(obj.x, obj.y))

                case 'maskedorc':
                    enemy = MaskedOrc(camera_group, start_pos=(obj.x, obj.y))

            entity_group.add(enemy)
            enemy_group.add(enemy)

As you can see, they are literally the exact same, the only difference is the name. The image attached shows the issue, one of them has the image blitted in the center of the green rect, which is whats wanted, and the other has the image blitted topleft of the green rect, which is not wanted.

I genuinely dk what to do, the classes are exactly the same, so they shouldn't be behaving differently. If anyone has any ideas, let me know.

Please reduce this to [mcve] form, as almost everything in that generic class is unrelated to reproducing the problem you're trying to debug. Show the code with all thee classes minified as far as you can get them, with just enough code so that if someone copy-and-pastes what's in your post, they see the same thing that you have in your image (and that might become a different image after you're done reducing, of course).

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans okay please give me a few minutes just to get it down

A heads up: elif obj.type in ('Enemy'): is wrong, or at least bad code smell. It will evaluate as true if obj.type is a substring of "Enemy" (e.g. "ne", "y", etc.), not just equal to "Enemy". Parentheses around a single value are for precedence only, they don't make a tuple. You want elif obj.type == "Enemy":, or (if all your other tests are against tuples and you want consistency in how the tests are written) elif obj.type in ("Enemy",): (note trailing comma after "Enemy" to make it a one-tuple).
